# Получение разного ID

Tags: jquery, веб-программирование, javascript

Вот столкнулся с такой проблемой:
Есть такой код:

```
<div class="u-menucont" style="overflow: visible; height: auto; width: 127px;" unselectable="on" id="WHEa5BBtED">
<div class="u-menuvitem">Пользователи</div>
<div class="u-menuvitem">Проверенные</div>
<div class="u-menuvitem">Модераторы</div>
<div class="u-menuvitem">Администраторы</div>
<div class="u-menuvitem">Друзья</div>
<div class="u-menuvitem"><div style="position:absolute;right:0;top:0;width:12px;height:16px;background: url(http://s24.ucoz.net/img/wd/1/ar2.gif) no-repeat 2px 8px;"></div><b>Заблокированные</b></div><div class="u-menuvitem" id="aAc">Гости</div>
</div>
```

Мне нужно, чтобы оно розставляло разные id в каждый элемент с классом *u-menuvitem*

```
Первая строчка - id: aAa
Вторая строчка - id: aAb
и т. д.
```

Например:
    <div class="u-menuvitem" id="aAa">Проверенные</div>
    <div class="u-menuvitem" id="aAb">Модераторы</div> 
    <div class="u-menuvitem" id="aAc">Администраторы</div>
    <div class="u-menuvitem" id="aAd">Друзья</div>

Comment: Надеюсь, поняли проблему -_-

Comment: @Юра Спивак, это [не проблема][1]. А сложность может быть в том, какой алгоритм для генерирования вам нужен. Вот например, после того, как дойдём до **aAz**, то переключаемся на **aBa** или как?

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/goqoxbwd/1/

Comment: Нет. Если оно дошло до aAz, то оно не должно больше ставить id.

Comment: @Юра Спивак, тогда [берите мой пример за основу][1]. Подправьте, если надо, и би хеппи.

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/goqoxbwd/2/

Comment: @Deonis, в примере работает, а на сайте не добавляет id.

Comment: @Юра Спивак, с консолью общались? Ошибки присутствуют? И проверьте правильность селекторов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что-то вроде такого?

```
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'];
$('.u-menuvitem').attr('id', function(index, value) {
    return 'aA' + arr[index];
});
```

Comment: Пишет id="aAundefined" у всех div.

Comment: Ошибка где-то у вас, у меня все работает - http://jsfiddle.net/gLgdjufn/1/

Comment: Спасибо большое, посмотрел, а у меня неправильно адрес был указан.